# How many numbers of base 3, of length $n$ are there that contain at least $1$ twos

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> My Attempts

First I wrote down some numbers
Of length one, there is only $1$ valid number - $2$
Of Length two there are $4$: $12, 20, 21, 22$
Of Length three there are $13$: $112, 120, ... , 221, 222$
....
Of that I got a sequence ${1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364, ...}$
I then found the relation
$$a_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
a_1 & = \ 1 \\
a_n & = \ a_{n-1} * 3 + 1
\end{array} \right.$$
Which is
$$ \frac{3^n - 1}{2}$$

Knowing that I wanted to prove this sequence holds for any string of length n.

I tried to prove this via combinations

-Of length one there are ${1}\choose{1}$  = 1 results
-Of length two there are ${2}\choose{1}$ + ${2}\choose{2}$ = 3 ?
That didn't work, so then I tried

-The total strings of length 1 minus the total with NO twos is $3^1$ - $2^1$ = $1$
-Of Length 2 is $3^2$ - $2^2$ = $5$ ?
This also doesn't work, so then I tried looking at the strings themselves again

The strings of length $2$ contains... $3$ strings with one $2$, $1$ with $2$ twos
The strings of length $3$ contains $7$ with $1$, $5$ with $2$, and $1$ with $3$
Of length $3$: $15$ with $1$, $17$ with $2$, $7$ with $3$, $1$ with $4$

Now I have all these numbers, but I am at a loss what to do with them.
Where did I go wrong about attempting to do this? (Probably something very blatant)
And how do I finish it?

Comment: Easier to work backwards.  How many ternary strings of length $n$ are there with no restriction?  How many binary strings of length $n$ are there?  Now subtract.

Comment: Note, I don't understand your examples.  Are you rejecting strings that begin with $0$?  Why?  Are there other exclusions?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I am rejecting strings that start with $0$: $021$, is the same as $21$. The strings are numbers of base 3 if that clears anything up.

Comment: You should edit your post to clarify that... That's not the usual definition of a ternary string.

Comment: The method I described still works though.

Comment: Recursion **unnecessary**, direct computation routine.  Given a set $~A,~$ with a finite number of elements, let $~|A|~$ denote the number of elements in the set $~A.$  Let $~S_n~$ denote the set of all ternary strings of length $~n.~$ Let $~S_{(n,0)}~$ denote the subset of $~S_n~$ that contains exactly $~0~$ "1"s, and let $~S_{(n,1)}~$ denote the subset of $~S_n~$ that contains exactly $~1~$ "1"s.  Then, the following values may be routinely (directly) computed, as a function of $~n: ~|S_n|, ~|S_{(n,0)}|, ~|S_{(n,1)}|.$  The desired computation is then $$|S_n| -  |S_{(n,0)}| -|S_{(n,1)}|.$$

Comment: Per one of your previous comments, the only refinement needed re my last comment is that you have outlawed strings that are zero-filled on the left.  So when computing (for example) $~|S_n|,~$ you only have two choices for the leftmost character, rather than three choices.  For simplicity, I suggest that you assume that $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$

Comment: Now that I take into account that a number cannot start with $0$ and cannot be all $0$s
For length $2$, the first digit can be a $1$, or a $2$ and the second can be a $0$,$1$, or $2$. This gives $2 * 3$ = $6$ as the total. Then I need to subtract the amount with none, so the fist digit can only be $1$ as it cannot be $0$ or $2$ and the second can be $0$ or $1$, so $1$ * $2$ = $2.$
This gives $6 - 2$ = $4$ as the first which seems to work.
For length $3$ the total is $2 * 3 * 3 $= $18$, and with no 2s is $1 * 2 * 2$ = $4$ But $18 - 4$ != $13$ which then confuses me.

Comment: In your list of length 3, I think you're missing 102. That would be the extra one to make the total 14

Comment: You are right! I asked the wrong question, but that does make sense for the actual question I asked.
 I don't really know how to ask the question that I wanted to ask though... in it $102$, would not be included in the groups of $3$ because it has a $0$ in front of the two. It would be considered length 1 because the 0 cuts the string. But thanks for answering! I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: It would take a whole story to explain, why I am trying to find it that way, and I am not sure if I explain, why it is like that in a new question. But the basics is that I was looking at the terms of ${2n}\choose{n}$ and noticed that variables divisible by 3 occurred in interesting groups. 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, ...
I also noticed that the base three expansion of the terms divisible by 3 contained a two in any position. 
Based on that I wanted find and prove a way that you can look at a term n and see whether ${2n}\choose{n}$ is divisible by 3 and the size of the group it is a part of.

Comment: The sequence in the question is [OEIS A003462](https://oeis.org/A003462) while the correct sequence is [OEIS A027649](https://oeis.org/A027649) offset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the comments, for problems like this where you have to count multiple cases (at least one $2$ includes exactly one $2$, exactly two $2$'s, ...), it's often easier to count the complement first to avoid the overlap double-counting challenge. So in this case,

Number of strings that contain at least one $2$ = Total number of strings - Number of strings that contain zero $2$'s

To qualify as a $n$-digit ternary string, first digit cannot be $0$. So there are only two possibilities: $1$ or $2$. The remaining $n-1$ digits can be either $0,1,2$ independently. So the total number of $n$-digit ternary strings is $2\times3^{n-1}$.

When there are zero $2$'s, that's basically counting the total number when only $0$ and $1$ are valid digits. Since $0$ cannot be the first digit, similar to above, we get $1\times2^{n-1}$.

So the number of $n$-digit ternary strings with at least one $2$, is $2\times3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1}$